# How to detect in runtime is KASLR enabled or disabled?

Tags: command-line, kernel

How to detect if KASLR is enabled or disabled in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your kernel command line. (example on debian 8)

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-`uname -r` root=/dev/mapper/`hostname`-root ro quiet
```

> kASLR is available starting with Ubuntu 14.10 but it is not enabled by
>   default. Specify the "kaslr" option on the kernel command line to use
>   kASLR.
>
> **Note:** Enabling kASLR will disable the ability to enter hibernation mode.

source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features

Comment: Now kASLR is enabled by default on Ubuntu. So this check won't work.  See @bhass1 or my answer for a better method of kASLR detection.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.14.27-041427-generic root=UUID=f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b ro quiet splash loglevel=0 vga=current udev.log-priority=3 fastboot kaslr acpiphp.disable=1 crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M vt.handoff=7
```

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't satisfied with the prior answers as they really don't get to the meat of validating what KASLR is all about - especially embedded or custom kernels that don't implement the same kernel command-line interface (e.g. ARM64 requires a device-tree chosen node called kaslr-seed to be present when the kernel boots. This is usually implemented by the bootloader using a secure random number generator).

At runtime I know of two things you can check:

1. the `/proc/kallsyms` file to see the symbol addresses in virtual memory address space.
2. `lsmod` to see the kernel module addresses in virtual memory address space. **Note:** On some machines, `lsmod` may not show the addresses. In that case, try using `cat /proc/modules` as root. If not using root, the addresses may be all zeros (cleared for security reasons). ~~Thanks to user @crass for the comment!~~

Both 1 & 2 are similar checks, but depending on what's available to you on your system, you might need to use one or the other.

#### 1. /proc/kallsyms

To do so, simply look at the first few lines of `/proc/kallsyms`:

```
root@device:~# head -n 3 /proc/kallsyms
ffffff8008080000 t _head
ffffff8008080000 T _text
ffffff8008080800 T do_undefinstr
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `_head` is `ffff ff80 0808 0000`.

Now reboot your machine and check again.

```
root@device:~# head -n 3 /proc/kallsyms
ffffff9fc8c80000 t _head
ffffff9fc8c80000 T _text
ffffff9fc8c80800 T do_undefinstr
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `_head` is now `ffff ff9f c8c8 0000`.
Compare the high-level bytes and find that `ffffff80080 != 0xffffff9fc8c` so the addresses are being changed across reboots => KASLR is enabled.

#### 2. lsmod

Similar to `/proc/kallsyms` method above: check lsmod, reboot, check lsmod again, and compare the addresses.

```
root@device:~# lsmod
iptable_filter 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffa1c49b9000
ip_tables 28672 1 iptable_filter, Live 0xffffffa1c49ad000
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `iptable_filter` is `ffff ffa1 c49b 9000`.

Now reboot your machine and check again.

```
root@device:~# lsmod
iptable_filter 16384 0 - Live 0xffffff2100716000
ip_tables 28672 1 iptable_filter, Live 0xffffff210070a000
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `iptable_filter` is now `ffff ff21 0071 6000`.
Compare the high-level bytes and find that `ffffff2100716 != 0xffffffa1c49b9` so the addresses are being changed across reboots => KASLR is enabled.

You can do these tests iteratively to determine the *quality* of the randomness. How different are the addresses across reboots? Are there obvious patterns? The security benefit of KASLR is proportional to the quality of randomness, or entropy.

References:
[Debugging Linux Kernels with KASL](https://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/kaslr/)
[Linux Kernel Driver Database for RANDOMIZE_BASE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RANDOMIZE_BASE.html)

Comment: On my machine `lsmod` does not show the module addresses. Using `cat /proc/modules` as root shows the addresses.  If not using root, the addresses may be all zeros (cleared for security reasons).

Answer (score 1):

I like @bhass1's answer here, however I didn't want to have to reboot my computer to do the test.  So you can perform essentially the same test but in a virtual machine, if that's available to you.  I'm using `qemu` with the `-kernel` and `-initrd` options, and here's how I do it:

First, I check which kernel you're running by looking at `cat /proc/cmdline`

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.2.0-42-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro vt.handoff=7
```

So I'm using **kernel** `vmlinuz-5.2.0-42-generic`.

We need to run the kernel with an initrd just to have a minimal environment to be able to check the addresses.  I use the initrd that corresponds to my kernel, to make the simulation more real, but it really should not matter.  I also use the kernel commandline of the running kernel, to keep the simulation as close to the running kernel as possible, and add `break=top` to the kernel commandline to get to a shell as quickly as possible.

Next, I run the `qemu` virtual machine:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-5.2.0-42-generic \
  -append "$(cat /proc/cmdline) break=top" -initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.2.0-42-generic
```

When I get to the shell I get the loaded module addresses:

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/modules
usbhid 57344 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0269000
hid 131072 1 usbhid, Live 0xffffffffc0248000
```

Now I'll check the running system to see what the module address is for one of the modules to see if its different:

```
sudo grep hid /proc/modules 
hid_generic 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc20ac000
usbhid 57344 0 - Live 0xffffffffc1a09000
hid 131072 2 hid_generic,usbhid, Live 0xffffffffc1c96000
```

So we can see here that the addresses for the **hid** module are different (running: `0xffffffffc1c96000` and virtual: `0xffffffffc0248000`).  So my kernel is running with kASLR, **even though** its not on the kernel command line (its turned on by default now on some distros).

You can check the module address again in another `qemu` instance and verify that the module address changes on every qemu run.  Also, you can add `nokaslr` to the kernel commandline (the `-append` `qemu` option) and run `qemu` a couple times to verify that the module addresses **do not** change.